# Signing a binary hash vs character representation of the same hash

Tags: rsa, signature

I have a hash that I want to sign, with the hexadecimal representation: hash_bin=0x11223344 (length 4 bytes).
The same hash also has a character representation hash_text=”11223344”, which is the binary stream {0x31, 0x31, 0x32, 0x32, 0x33, 0x33, 0x34, 0x34} (length 8 bytes).

Which of the hash versions (hash_bin – 4 bytes / hash_text – 8 bytes) is better to use for signing the hash by RSA, security-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of the hash versions (hash_bin – 4 bytes / hash_text – 8 bytes) is better to use for signing the hash by RSA, security-wise?

Doesn't matter; as long as there is a 1:1 relationship between versions, it doesn't matter which representation you sign.

The only situation where you might run into a problem is if two different hashes (with version A) mapped to the same hash (with version B) - that doesn't happen here.

Now, with RSA, we (almost) always hash the message being performing the actual low-level RSA operation - are you doing the traditional RSA signature method here (which would involve computing a hash of your hash)?  Or, are you expecting to take the hash you have, do RSA padding (you *are* doing RSA padding, aren't you), and then doing the RSA private operation)?

Comment: The hash is actually a 32-byte hash (64 characters) of a large binary image. I plan to use it as an input to the rsa_sign() function, which does the extra hashing, padding and private operations. @poncho